# Failure in paging due to load GridView and the DropDownList in the same Page.PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview that it needs to be within a postback to able to execute an update by selecting a checkbox. The problem is that I have a filter using a DropDownList, if I leave my PopularGVDuplicatas () within the same postback where items are loaded, the filter does not work and paging as well. If I leave the PopularGVDuplicatas () outside the postback the checkbox when checked does not work as it should. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
private static string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["string"].ConnectionString;
private string SQL = "select";
private double somaSelecionados = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlFiltro.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Somente abertas"));
        ddlFiltro.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Já pagas"));
        ddlFiltro.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Ambas"));

        PopularGVDuplicatas();
    }
}

public void PopularGVDuplicatas()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strCon);

    if (ddlFiltro.Text.Equals("Somente abertas"))
    {
        SQL = "select";
    }
    else if (ddlFiltro.Text.Equals("Já pagas"))
    {
        SQL = "select";
    }
    else if (ddlFiltro.Text.Equals("Ambas"))
    {
        SQL = "select";
    }
    else
    {
        SQL = "select";
    }

    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    conn.Open();
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }

    gvDuplicatas.AllowPaging = true;
    gvDuplicatas.PageSize = 100;
    gvDuplicatas.PagerSettings.Position = PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
    gvDuplicatas.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast;
    gvDuplicatas.PagerSettings.PageButtonCount = 50;

    gvDuplicatas.PagerStyle.CssClass = "pagination-ys";
    gvDuplicatas.PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

    gvDuplicatas.DataSource = dt;
    gvDuplicatas.DataBind();

}

protected void gvDuplicatas_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvDuplicatas.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvDuplicatas.SelectedIndex = -1;

    PopularGVDuplicatas();
}
protected void gvDuplicatas_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "diasatraso") != DBNull.Value)
        {
            string data = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "dtpagamento").ToString();
            string diasatraso = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "diasatraso").ToString();

            if ((!ValidaData(data)) && ((Convert.ToInt16(diasatraso)) == 0))
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#0000A0");
            }
            else if ((!ValidaData(data)) && ((Convert.ToInt16(diasatraso)) < 0))
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("");
            }
            else if ((!ValidaData(data)) && ((Convert.ToInt16(diasatraso)) > 0))
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#FF0000");
            }
            else if ((ValidaData(data)))
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#468647");
            }
        }

        bool ativo = true;

        ativo = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelecionar")).Checked;
        if (ativo)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#ffffb3");
        }
    }
}

public bool ValidaData(string data)
{
    DateTime resultado = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(data, out resultado))
        return true;

    return false;
}

protected void chkSelecionar_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkSelecionar = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkSelecionar.NamingContainer;

    string duplicata = row.Cells[1].Text;
    string vrduplicata = row.Cells[6].Text;

    bool status = chkSelecionar.Checked;

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strCon);

    if (status)
    {
        string SQL = "update command";
        MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand(SQL, conn);

        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duplicata", Convert.ToInt32(duplicata));

        conn.Open();
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        //somaSelecionados += Convert.ToDouble(vrduplicata);
        //lblValorTotal.Text = somaSelecionados.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        string SQL = "update command";
        MySqlCommand cmdUpdate = new MySqlCommand(SQL, conn);

        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duplicata", Convert.ToInt32(duplicata));

        conn.Open();
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }

    PopularGVDuplicatas();
}
```

**Solved.**
I put or put the PopularGVDuplicatas() within the event ddlFiltro_TextChanged and it worked.

Comment: Can you remove PopularGVDuplicatas() first from your Page_Load and see what item is checked?

Comment: If I remove the PopularGVDuplicatas(), the gridview will not charge. The checkbox is inside the gridview.

Comment: Can you define "does not work", do they simply do nothing?

Comment: It works, but it does not return the correct result. If I leave the PopularGVDuplicatas() out of the condition if(!Page.IsPostBack) my filter ddlFiltro works, but my checkbox in filter does not work anymore. If I leave the PopularGVDuplicatas() within the condition if(! Page.IsPostBack), my ddlFiltro filter does not work as it should.